# How to use Jackson to deserialize to list or value based upon JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a json in following format, where in key represents the attribute type and value represents the value of that attribute.

```
{ "attributes":
[
  {
    "key":"name",
    "value":"Archit"
  },
  { 
    "key":"website",
    "value":"stackoverflow"
  },
  { 
    "key":"languages",
    "value":[
              "python",
              "java",
              "c++"
            ]
  }
]
}
```

I am trying to map it to an following java object using jackson :

```
public class Attributes {
  List<Attribute> attributes;
}



public abstract class Attribute {
  String key;
}



public class SingleValuedAttribute extends Attribute{
  String value;
}


public class MultiValuedAttribute extends Attribute{
  List<String> value;
}


  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Attributes attributes = mapper.readValue(new File(jsonFilePath), Attributes.class);
```

I tried having a look at polymorphic deserialization but that required type info in the json object, which doesn't exist in my json ?

Any tips on how to do this ?

PS:
I can't change the json format.
The list of keys is not bounded/limited.

Comment: You will likely have to use a custom `JsonDeserializer` to map to either of your `Attribute` implementations depending on if you get an array or an object.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the difference between `SingleValuedAttribute` and `MultiValuedAttribute` classes. `SingleValuedAttribute` class represents one element array. You could simplify your POJO classes hierarchy by deleting it.

Please, see below example how it could looks like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

        File json = new File("/x/test.json");
        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(json, Attributes.class));
    }
}

class Attributes {

    private List<Attribute> attributes;

    //getters, setters
}

class Attribute {

    private String key;
    private List<String> value;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Above program prints:

```
[Attribute [key=name, value=[Archit]], Attribute [key=website, value=[stackoverflow]], Attribute [key=languages, value=[python, java, c++]]]
```